# Mqtt connection fails when connecting to public brokers

Tags: c#, .net, mqtt

I am trying to connect to some mqtt public brokers for test, but I can't connect to any.

I tried to follow these instruction for the code: https://docs.emqx.com/en/cloud/latest/connect_to_deployments/c_sharp_sdk.html#connection

with error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

I tried to connect to other public servers as broker.hivemq.com, mqtt.eclipse.org, test.mosquitto.org

But nothing seems to work. Did anyone succeed to connect to a public broker with c#?
I would highly appreciate any recommendations

```
using System;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Messages;

namespace csharpMQTT
{
    class Program
    {
        static MqttClient ConnectMQTT(string broker, int port, string clientId, string username, string password)
        {
            MqttClient client = new MqttClient(broker, port, false, MqttSslProtocols.None, null, null);
            client.Connect(clientId, username, password);
            if (client.IsConnected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connected to MQTT Broker");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to connect");
            }
            return client;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string broker = "broker.emqx.io";
            int port = 1883;
            string clientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            string username = "emqx";
            string password = "public";
            MqttClient client = ConnectMQTT(broker, port, clientId, username, password);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I tried to eliminate credentials:

```
using System;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Messages;

namespace csharpMQTT
{
    class Program
    {
        static MqttClient ConnectMQTT(string broker, int port, string clientId)
        {
            MqttClient client = new MqttClient(broker, port, false, MqttSslProtocols.None, null, null);
            client.Connect(clientId);
            if (client.IsConnected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connected to MQTT Broker");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to connect");
            }
            return client;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string broker = "broker.hivemq.com";
            int port = 1883;
            string clientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            MqttClient client = ConnectMQTT(broker, port, clientId);
        }
    }
}
```

I used target framework for project : .Net Core 3.1 and nuget package M2Mqtt 4.3.0

Comment: If you actually want people to be able to help you, then please provide your code.  Please see:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.    Otherwise, I'm sorry to say that you will likely find this question closed, which won't be of help to you.

Comment: Hello, I didn't provide the code because I used exactly the same from the link. But I put it here explicitly now

Comment: Did you take the credentials and endpoint from your Deployment overview page? https://docs.emqx.com/en/cloud/latest/deployments/view_deployment.html#view-deployment-information

Comment: Sample code from https://docs.emqx.com/en/cloud/latest/connect_to_deployments/c_sharp_sdk.html#connection worked for me. Maybe it is a network issue? Are you behind firewall or proxy?

Comment: @Nikolay Yes, I have firewall and I enabled inbound rules to enable connections for port 1883. Can you specify, please, which version of .net framework and nuget package did you use? Thank you very much

Comment: @bags I think, you need to open outbound connections on port 1883. I used dotnet 6.0.405 in WSL2 and M2Mqtt 4.3.0